# SharePoint - How to disable edit item access to the creator once the item is moved to "pending" status?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-clientobject

I am developing a simple SharePoint site application in which I'm trying to incorporate the below scenario.

"Once the creator submitted an item, the creator should not edit the item".

I have set "Yes" to "Require content approval for submitted items?"

In the current system, it allows the creator of the item to edit once the item is in "Pending" status. I do not want the creator to edit the item. Is there any solution to customize this using Clienet Object Model?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set item level permission to achieve this. You can create item level permission using sharepoint designer 2010 workflow. This feature is not available in 2013 workflows but you can deploy 2010 workflows for sharepoint 2013 as well. You wil have to do the below things:
1.Create SharePoint designer 2010 workflow (Select 2010 workflow even if your site is SharePoint 2013 site).
2. Add an impersonation step. Inside impersonation steps you can see actions to manipulate permission.
3.Check the status is pending.  Add "Replace permission" action and give the Created By user "Read" permission on that item.
4.Add another condition to check if the status is not pending . Then use "Replace permission" action to give him contribute rights.
5. Make the workflow trigger on item created and updated.

Below is link on setting item level permission on SPD 2010 workflows.

http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html